# Hated here...? Should I unsubscribe?

Tags: discussion

My question has been down-voted, at least three times (I'm not a high-k user and thus unable to see by whom, not even able to see the number of up/down-votes, only the outcome.)

I'm really pissed off by that, is there a possibility to delete all my previous actions (Q,A, Comments) and just leave you all by your own?

Edit: I really want to quit.
I deleted questions with no answers all right, but I'm not allowed to
delete questions that have answers.

Comment: First, we do not hate you; Second,  don't worry too much about downvotes - read this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397?s=1|0.5885#215397); Third, could you link some of your downvoted questions, perhaps I was one of the downvoters - happy to elaborate quickly if applicable. Fourth; deleting answered questions can be done only by mods, and should be prevented at all times. However, anyone can delete their account, if I am not mistaken, but why should you?

Comment: Just for the record - since you specifically ask - yes, you can delete your account. See my answer to [this meta question](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3239/how-do-i-fully-delete-my-biology-stack-exchange-account) for further information.

Comment: Try to stick around a bit longer though, and ignore the occational downvote. Several of your questions are clearly appreciated by the community.

Comment: @fileunderwater 3 consecutive down-votes within about 5 minutes after posting clearly tells me that there is something wrong. None of the down-voters leaving any hint on "why" that would give me any chance to improve rings some bells, reminding me of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

1. **You are not hated**
2. Most of your questions are upvoted. The three downvotes you are talking about are on your highest voted question. Nevermind. It has much more upvotes.
3. Nobody can see who voted on their posts, including the mods.
4. Sometimes some people may downvote for incomprehensible reasons. Happened with me and many other high-rep users too. So don't worry.
5. Don't take a petty downvote to your heart.
6. Sometimes some people may have genuine reasons for downvoting something. Some people would comment along with the vote so that you may improve the post. However, that is not an obligation.
7. If you want to ask why a question of yours was closed (put on hold) then you can ask in meta.

Comment: touche, well said.

Comment: "Nevermind. It has much more upvotes.": those are compensational up-votes. (I don't think the question is good enough to have more than about 2 *real* up-votes). But I have not yet been told why it would deserve 3 down-votes in a very short time. I can't improve if feedback is only by anonymous ass-kicking.

Answer (score 2):

I second WYSIWYG -

- First, we do not hate you;
- Second, don't worry too much about downvotes - read this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397). Downvotes are an integral part of SE and in fact, Bio has a strong tendency for *very conservative downvoting* (and quite conservative upvoting too, for that matter);
- Third, could you link some of your downvoted questions, perhaps I was one of the downvoters - happy to elaborate quickly if applicable.
- Fourth; deleting answered questions can be done only by mods, and should be prevented at all times. However, anyone can delete their account, if I am not mistaken, but why should you?
- Last, my first questions and answers were shot at too - it is the ones that deal with criticism in a positive way and integrate it as part of a learning curve that eventually make it up high in the food chain as active and valuable members of this community. Bringing this up in meta is a good first step in that process. Do not take downvotes personally. It happened now, it will happen again; it is an integral part of the SE philosophy and is meant to allow, and push users to improve their contributions.